# Google Sheets QUERY function - how to reference the active sheet/tab name?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

It *seems* simple, but I can't get it to work. I've searched through many articles and get close, but no cigar.  I wrote code to make a tab for all of our managers, which worked fine. Now I want to use the QUERY function to break out the data for each individual manager from the first tab that houses the data for all managers. But rather than type each managers name into each QUERY function on each tab, I would like to reference the sheet/tab name that I created for each individual manager.

This works:

```
=QUERY(StaffDetail!A1:E338,"SELECT B,C,E,A WHERE A = 'Doe, Jane'",1)
```

I tried putting code in the Script Editor to create a function that calls the sheet name, and then putting it in the QUERY formula; but it doesn't work.

```
function sheetName() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
}
```

Does not work:

```
=QUERY(StaffDetail!A1:E338,"SELECT B,C,E,A WHERE A = sheetName()",1)
```

I get these errors:
[image]

I don't understand why it doesn't work. I read about INDIRECT and some others, but this is on the same sheet so I don't think I would need that? Any help is appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation / Issue:

- Your custom function returns `Sheet` but your query formula accepts `'Sheet'`.
- I tried multiple things but only [CONCAT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093592?hl=en) seemed to work (concatenate would work as well).

### Solution:

Two modifications:

**Change your custom formula to:**

```
function sheetName() {
  return `'${SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName()}'`;
}
```

and that will return `'Sheet1'` assuming `Sheet1` is the active sheet.

**Change your google sheet formula to:**

```
=QUERY(StaffDetail!A1:E338, CONCAT("SELECT B,C,E,A WHERE A =", sheetName()),1)
```

[image]

---

**References:**

I used [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to make the function return `'Sheet'`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Marios. To make sure I understand - because the formula using the function looks at it as a string, you needed to make the function in GAS look at it as a string as well? By putting the tic marks in the function, that turned it into a string. I think it's brilliant and you saved me a lot of time.  Thank you again!

Comment: @Karen glad it solved your issue. The custom function returns a string but not in the correct way. It has to be `'sheet'` instead of `sheet` but both are strings.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification Marios!